# Persistent volume to windows not working on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, volume

I have map windows folder into me linux machine with

```
mount -t cifs //AUTOCHECK/OneStopShopWebAPI -o user=someuser,password=Aa1234 /xml_shared
```

and the following command

> df -hk

give me

```
//AUTOCHECK/OneStopShopWebAPI   83372028   58363852   25008176  71% /xml_shared
```

after that I create yaml file with

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-nfs-jenkins-slave
spec:
  storageClassName: jenkins-slave-data
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-jenkins-slave
  labels:
    type: jenkins-slave-data2
spec:
  storageClassName: jenkins-slave-data
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.100.109
    path: "//AUTOCHECK/OneStopShopWebAPI/jenkins_slave_shared"
```

this seems to not work when I create new pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jenkins-slave
  labels:
    label: jenkins-slave
spec:
  containers:
  - name: node
    image: node
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_slave_shared
          name: jenkins-slave-vol
  volumes:
    - name: jenkins-slave-vol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-nfs-jenkins-slave
```

do i need to change the nfs ? what is wrong with me logic?

Comment: Please take a look at: [Kubernetes CIFS](https://github.com/fstab/cifs)

Answer (score 1):

The mounting of CIFS share under Linux machine is correct but you need to take different approach to mount CIFS volume under Kubernetes. Let me explain:

There are some differences between [NFS and CIFS](https://ipwithease.com/difference-between-cifs-and-nfs/).

This site explained the whole process step by step: [Github CIFS Kubernetes](https://github.com/fstab/cifs).

Comment: it's looks good, but I choose to mount the driver to local folder and then define a regular mount to this folder, then i choose to run all this container on this folder. so thank you very much and I guessing I will use your answer in near future